# Hide csrf token in get method in the django

Tags: django, django-csrf

How can I hide the CSRF token from the get method in the Django? When we call the get method then only the parameters need to visible in the browser URL rather than the CSRF token.

Answer (score 7):

The CSRF protection ignores GET requests (see [how it works](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/csrf/#how-it-works)). Therefore you can simply remove `{% csrf_token%}` from the form in your template.

```
<form method="get" action=".">
  {% csrf_token %}<!-- remove this line -->
  {{ form }}
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

Remove `{% csrf_token %}` from your form in the template, you don't need it since you're making a GET request.